# Detect eyes in real time video with Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, face-detection, core-image

I was checking [this Apple sample code, Squarecam](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/SquareCam/Listings/SquareCam_SquareCamViewController_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011190-SquareCam_SquareCamViewController_m-DontLinkElementID_7). there are also some examples out there written in Swift.

In this example, a red square is drawn when a face is detected. My question is: How can circles be drawn at the eyes?

I still don't know how to detect the eyes in a similar way they did it in the example with the face.

Or how the position of the eyes (faceFeature.leftEyePosition) can be used for drawing the circle.

Any ideas?

Comment: Here is the class I´m using: This is the [link](http://pastebin.com/F9ikyFk7)

In the method: drawFaces the image moustache is added. The example doesn´t use the properties hasMouth of .mouthPosition of the face feature object.

If I want to use the properties leftEyePosition and rightEyePosition, how can I add glasses/lens by using those values?

Answer (score 0):

The face feature gives you a point of the feature inside the Image bounds.

```
open var leftEyePosition: CGPoint { get }
```

you can build a rectangle around the point. Once you have the rectangle you can create a layer and composite over the face image.

```
 if let overlay = CIImage(color: overlayColor).cropping(to: faceImage.extent).applyingPerspectiveTransformFilter(onRect: eyeRect)
  {
   let eyeMarkedImage = overlay.compositingOverImage(faceImage)
  }
```

The "`applyingPerspectiveTransformFilter`" and "`cropping`" are the CIFilters.